# How to know the ActivemQ version?

Tags: activemq-classic

Can any one help me in this.
How can I know which version of Apache ActiveMQ is installed on my system

I want to know from my Apache ActiveMQ console which version of Apache ActiveMQ is installed on my system.

Comment: What do you mean by activemq console, which console do you refer to?

Comment: @user3747182 You will see it on ActiveMQ web console start page. The same goes for hawt.io which displays the broker version if you click the broker in the tree.

Comment: To whoever voted to close this question, I'm quite clueless as to the reason. I know this is not a "programming question", but it seems like a "programming tools" question and there are other similar questions on the site.

Comment: you can access to your activemq page via http:// localhost or ipaddr:8186 then you probably will see a link "Manage ActiveMQ broker" which you need to login. then you can see the version as well as other informations such memory usage, ID, etc.

Answer (score 7):

```
activemq --version
```

The above command will display the activemq version information.

Reference : http://activemq.apache.org/activemq-command-line-tools-reference.html

Comment: If there is no activemq on the path try `/opt/activemq/bin/activemq --version`.